# Implicit conversion integer <--> logical in Fortran if statement

Tags: fortran, gfortran

I have some legacy Fortran code which I was asked to analyze and translate to a modern language. I don't know which compiler was used in the past to compile the code, so for now, I'm trying to compile it with gfortran. The code contains a statement like this was causes gfortran to complain:

```
  program test
  implicit none
  integer*4 :: var
  var=.true.

  if(var) then
        write(*,*) "Hi"
  endif

  end program test
```

Compiling this with gfortran gives the following error:

```
test.f:6:9:

       if(var) then
         1
Error: IF clause at (1) requires a scalar LOGICAL expression
```

(In addition, it gives a warning about the conversion done in `var=.true.`).

I'm not sure which which compiler the code was compiled, but apparently the code should compile as it is. Is there a way to tell gfortran to accept this conversion?

According to the docs, no implicit conversion is done within if-statements though: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gfortran/Implicitly-convert-LOGICAL-and-INTEGER-values.html

Comment: I can't answer the question (as I don't know how to get gfortran to compile this broken code), but can you just make `var` logical?

Comment: Yes that would work, but I would prefer not to change the code..

Comment: A perfectly reasonable desire.  A warning, though: if there are these non-standard parts in the code then there's no telling what else is going on (which may surprise you) that your compiler isn't complaining about.  It may be worth looking to see which compiler was originally used.

Comment: If you don't want to change your code to Fortran, how can you insist on a Fortran compiler to compile it?

Comment: @VladimirF : I don't insist on it, i was asking "Is there a way to tell gfortran to accept this conversion?". I have currently no idea about the code, what it does nor which compiler was used 20 years ago. I try to figure out what it does and to do so, it would be nice to be able to compile it

Comment: Intel will compile this. Gfortran won't you have found the manual entry about it yourself so you see yourself it is not possible in gfortran. Should we copy the manual to an answer for you? Be aware there are other issues too. `.true.` in gfortran is +1, but in Intel (DEC,Compaq), it is -1.

Comment: From your link: "However, there is no implicit conversion of INTEGER values in if-statements, nor of LOGICAL or INTEGER values in I/O operations. " Should we just put it to an answer?

Comment: @VladimirF yes put it to an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not possible in GFortran. The [manual](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gfortran/Implicitly-convert-LOGICAL-and-INTEGER-values.html) states:

> However, there is no implicit conversion of INTEGER values in
>   if-statements, nor of LOGICAL or INTEGER values in I/O operations.

You are only able to perform implicit conversions in assignments like your

```
  integer :: var
  var = .true.
```

but even there you must be very careful. It is not standard conforming and the value `var` will differ between compilers. Intel used to use `-1` (all bits set to 1), unless `-standard-semantics` was chosen, for `.true.`, but gfortran uses `+1` as in the C language. New versions of Intel Fortran changes the default. The other direction is even trickier, there might be values which are neither `.true.` nor `.false.`.

Comment: Intel changed their default years ago. The current default is "var /= 0" and "transfer(.TRUE.,0)=1". The old default was indeed "iand(var,1) /= 0" and "transfer(.TRUE.,0)=-1". The compiler may still have bugs when you feed transfer(2,.FALSE.) to some of its intrinsics and choose one or the other of its documented internal representations.

Comment: This question was written, well a year and something ago. But many people still use older versions. It is not such a distant past when I discussed the behaviour here with Steve Lionel. It was especially confusing with `logical(c_bool)` which did not work properly without `-standard-semantics`.

Comment: That's one issue with this forum is that a lot of the posts are resurrected from years ago, so if you forget to check dates you are out of phase with context. The standard should have recommended that implementors set C_BOOL=-1 because C doesn't have a LOGICAL type (_Bool is an integer type) and trying to get Fortran LOGICAL to match C _Bool means that Fortran LOGICAL will become just as broken as C. TT

Comment: That would be wrong! Yes, it is an integer, but still making the LOGICAL interoperable is still useful.

Comment: What is 'that' which would be wrong? And what am I wrong about?

Comment: That c_bool is useless and it should be -1.

Comment: What is 'that' which would be wrong? And what am I wrong about? OK, I saw your edit. C's definition of _Bool means that implementors can make the destructive choice that gcc does that anything other that B'00000000' or B'00000001' and your program behaves randomly. Pre MIL-STD 1753 FORTRAN used LOGICAL operations to perform masking operations. The gcc implementation of _Bool and gfortran's value of C_BOOL=1 breaks this old code. Timed out during editing.

Comment: What kind of masking do you have in mind? Why is the old code relevant for modern Fortran-C interoperability? If you are passing anything else than 0 or 1 between C and Fortran then you are breaking a contract in the ABI and it is only your fault if the program behaves bad. The same kind of problem as transfering a random Fortran integer to a Fortran logical.

Comment: Like IFLAGS = IANY([IFLAG2,IFLAG5,IFLAG7]). In the old days you needed to write IFLAGS = IFLAG2 .OR. IFLAG5 .OR. IFLAG7 and rely on an extension that could be implemented as converting the inputs to LOGICAL, performing the .OR. binary operations, then converting back to INTEGER. Conversions performed via TRANSFER. With gfortran the expression is documented as intentionally broken, and it can be traced to the broken nature of C _Bool, but it affects programs that never heard of C.

Comment: Su h code was not standard conforming and can't be expected to work on a different platform or with a different compiler. The choice gfortran did is perfectly standard conforming and I believe it was already present in g77 if not even f2c. Way before _Bool and iso_c_binding.

Comment: I guess it's like any of those cat person/dog person, Linux geek/Windows geek, BLINK/Miracle things, we just have to agree to disagree.