# Convert a complicated condition from C to Fortran

Tags: c, fortran, gfortran

I have a small C function to convert Fortran

```
baralign(n, b)  {   

  return ((n&~(~0<<b)) ? (n&(~0<<b))+(1<<b):(n))

}
```

I wrote the condition in above statement as follows in Fortran

```
if (IAND(n,NOT(ISHFT(NOT(0),b))))
```

I am not sure about this condition. When I run this code, it makes an error saying

```
IF clause requires a scalar LOGICAL expression.
```

Comment: +1 For converting to Fortran and not from Fortran to C++, Python or Java. -1 For an unclear problem. We need to know what you are not sure about? Are you unsure about the translation to Fortran or do you need to explain the C condition first? Can you explain to Fortran programmers what the code does and what should be the output? Please also alwys show more of the code, not just one line. See [ask]. Also always use tag `fortran` for all Fortran questions. Did you get any error message?

Comment: From a short view the condition looks OK, but then you need to test if it is `/=0` or not. You cannot use integers in ifs in the same way as in C. Did you get any error message? If yes, you must always show it.

Comment: I want to convert  this  c code,  if (IAND(n,NOT(ISHFT(NOT(0),b)))) to FORTRAN.   This is a c condition with a bit-wise operations. When I run this code, it makes a error says "IF clause  requires a scalar LOGICAL expression|"

Comment: thank you , when I use the condition with /=0 it looks no error.

Comment: Good, but you should **really** improve your question. Otherwise people are voting against (-3 already) it and when you have too many downvoted questions you can be banned from this server. People are also voting to close your question because it is too unclear.

Comment: Ok, noted and thank you

Comment: Just on a side note here, be aware that `operator<<` and `ISHFT(I,SHIFT)` are identical for `SHIFT` bigger then zero. But `operator>>` and `ISHIFT(I,SHIFT)` with negative `SHIFT` are not. The C/
C++ version keeps track of the sign. (See [section 8.8 of the C++ std](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2017/n4659.pdf) and [section 13.7.4 of the Fortran std](http://www.j3-fortran.org/doc/year/10/10-007.pdf))

Comment: Ok, noted and thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is related to question [Implicit conversion integer <--> logical in Fortran if statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37293641/fortran-implicit-conversion-integer-logical-in-if-statement) , however that question is slightly different because the asker there is aware of the nature of the problem.

You cannot put an integer expression into an if condition in Fortran as you do in C

```
integer :: n, b

if (IAND(n,NOT(ISHFT(NOT(0),b))))
```

is not possible. The condition must be a `logical` expression.

If it should be true for any non-zero value of the integer expression, then you must put there an integer comparison

```
if (IAND(n,NOT(ISHFT(NOT(0),b))) /= 0) then
```

If you require the expression to be exactly 1, you could use `== 1` instead.

The rest will likely be

```
  baralign = IAND(n,ISHFT(NOT(0),b)) + ISHFT(1, b)
else
  baralign = n
end if
```

but I don't know the purpose of the code so I can't be sure.

Comment: Can you translate this into Fortran? There are intrinsics such as MERGE, IBITS, MASKL, MASKR, IBSET, and SHIFTL.