# Use of arithmetic if in fortran 77

Tags: fortran, fortran77

I have a question about arithmetic if in f77. If I get it properly it was supposed to be used that way:

```
if(integer) st-,st0,st+
```

and meant that st- was done if the integer was <0, st0 was done if integer = 0, and st+ for integer > 0.

I have a case like this:

```
 IF(number) test=0
```

I am right assuming test=0 statement will be done if number is lower than 0?

Thanks

Comment: An arithmetic `IF` always has three branches; this is a simple logical `IF`. If this is really a `number` and not a logical variable, then the (non-standard) semantics should be that it tests if `number` is not `0` (equivalent to `.false.`), i.e. `if (number .ne. 0)`.

Comment: @JeroenMostert ok thanks, and yes it is a number, an integer, my compiler didn't like it :-)

Comment: In an arithmetic if the things like `st-` aren't "done": they are labels for branching.  In an if the `test=0` is an action statement (which _is_ done).

Answer (score 1):

Your example code is a normal logical if, but with an integer instead of a logical expression for the condition. Some compilers (Intel and predecessors - DEC, Compaq) do allow that as a non-standard extension, gfortran does not. As far as I know not even with an option like `-fdec`.

See [Implicit conversion integer <--> logical in Fortran if statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37293641/implicit-conversion-integer-logical-in-fortran-if-statement) for more.

What an arithmetic if does is that it selects one of the three branches using numeric statement labels, you cannot put executable statements after an arithmetic if.

```
if(integer) label-,label0,label+
```

That means, e.g.,

```
if (i) 10, 20, 30

10 do something

20 do something else

30 do something else
```